# Can't retrieve data from database (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to retrieve my data from my database but I do not know how to do this (I am new to the Android studio). After some research
I got to this code below 
but it's not working
I want to retrieve the information from "Documeto" by
looking for the attribute "cpf".
basiclly I want the user to get the 'Documeto' info by  searching it's "cpf" on the app.

```
  public void BuscarDoc(){



        String Cpf = txtBusc.getText().toString().trim();
        Toast.makeText(this, Cpf, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //databaseDoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("duscadi");
        //DatabaseReference ref = databaseDoc.child("Documento");
        databaseDoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query =databaseDoc.child("Documento").child("cpf").equalTo(Cpf);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Documento doc = dataSnapshot.getValue(Documento.class);

                    System.out.println("ta normal");
                    if (doc != null){
                        System.out.println("o objetyo ta salvo");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("tA NUZAÇO");
                    }
                }
                //Documento doc = dataSnapshot.getValue(Documento.class);
                //System.out.println(doc);
                //System.out.println("cupameupaui");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

inactivity disconnecting from the service

Comment: Hello Ratonildo, can you please specify what "is not working" means. 
When developing for Android use `Log` instead of `System.out.println` to log messages. I'd also try to log the databaseError in the `onCancelled` method. You should then be able to get error messages in the `Logcat` window in Android Studio

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data you want to get and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @RatonildoRamon Don't put your source codes in the Answer section. it would misguide someone. Edit your original post and add them to it.